# how to apply css for the form

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form that opens when the website is loaded it should have a close button on the top right corner. I have tried but the outcome is shown below [image]

This is the code I tried :

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
    <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
      <h1>Admission Form</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button>

      <input type="text" placeholder=" Name" name="username" required><br/>

      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>

      <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required><br/>

      <select class="branches">
        <option value="volvo">Select a branch</option>
        <option value="icse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE</option>
        <option value="cbse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE</option>
        <option value="mysore">RCIS,Mysuru</option>
        <option value="sarjapur">RCIS,Sarjapur</option>
        <option value="begur">RCIS,Begur</option>
        <option value="mspalya">RCIS,MS Palya</option>
        <option value="chamrajpet">RCIS,Chamrajpet</option>
      </select><br/>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Grade for Applying" name="grade" required><br/>


      <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob" required><br/>


      <button type="submit" class="btn">Enquire Now</button>
      <!-- <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button> -->
    </form>
  </div>
```

This is the `CSS` part:

```
    .form-container .cancel {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
  }
```

Can I know how to apply `css` for the close button that should appear right next to the heading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<h1>` is a block element, so that's why it will occupy its own horizontal region and push other elements down.

You could float the close button to the right and use `position: relative` and `top`, `left` to adjust it.

```css
#myForm.form-popup {
  width: 320px
}

.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

button.btn.cancel {
  float: right;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px
}
```

```html
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">✕</button>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
    <h1>Admission Form</h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder=" Name" name="username" required><br/>

    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>

    <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required><br/>

    <select class="branches">
      <option value="volvo">Select a branch</option>
      <option value="icse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE</option>
      <option value="cbse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE</option>
      <option value="mysore">RCIS,Mysuru</option>
      <option value="sarjapur">RCIS,Sarjapur</option>
      <option value="begur">RCIS,Begur</option>
      <option value="mspalya">RCIS,MS Palya</option>
      <option value="chamrajpet">RCIS,Chamrajpet</option>
    </select><br/>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Grade for Applying" name="grade" required><br/>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob" required><br/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Enquire Now</button>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button> -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Another way is to use `positive: relative` on the container and `position: absolute` for the button and `top` and `right` to position it:

```css
#myForm.form-popup {
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
}

.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

button.btn.cancel {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">✕</button>
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
    <h1>Admission Form</h1>

    <input type="text" placeholder=" Name" name="username" required><br/>

    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>

    <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required><br/>

    <select class="branches">
      <option value="volvo">Select a branch</option>
      <option value="icse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE</option>
      <option value="cbse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE</option>
      <option value="mysore">RCIS,Mysuru</option>
      <option value="sarjapur">RCIS,Sarjapur</option>
      <option value="begur">RCIS,Begur</option>
      <option value="mspalya">RCIS,MS Palya</option>
      <option value="chamrajpet">RCIS,Chamrajpet</option>
    </select><br/>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Grade for Applying" name="grade" required><br/>

    <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob" required><br/>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Enquire Now</button>
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button> -->
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **margin** and **padding** propert of CSS. It will help you

Answer (score 1):

> Simply you can just use in your css section for close button. It is as simple as that

```
right: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough to position the button.

The `h1` tag has a `display:block` default definition so it occupies the whole row.

Normally the close buttons on a modal window would use something like this:

```css
.cancel {
   position: absolute;
   top: 20px;
   right: 20px;
}
```

And just in case the container doesn't have position relative, you can add

```css
.form-popup {
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the closeForm button outside of the form tag

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button>
        <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
          <h1>Admission Form</h1>

          <input type="text" placeholder=" Name" name="username" required><br/>

          <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>

          <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" required><br/>

          <select class="branches">
            <option value="volvo">Select a branch</option>
            <option value="icse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar ICSE</option>
            <option value="cbse">RCIS,Kalyan Nagar CBSE</option>
            <option value="mysore">RCIS,Mysuru</option>
            <option value="sarjapur">RCIS,Sarjapur</option>
            <option value="begur">RCIS,Begur</option>
            <option value="mspalya">RCIS,MS Palya</option>
            <option value="chamrajpet">RCIS,Chamrajpet</option>
          </select><br/>

          <input type="text" placeholder="Grade for Applying" name="grade" required><br/>


          <input type="text" placeholder="Date of Birth" name="dob" required><br/>


          <button type="submit" class="btn">Enquire Now</button>
          <!-- <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">X</button> -->
        </form>
      </div>`enter code here`
```

Then you can use css to float the button to the right and give it a position of relative

```
.cancel {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    /* Add Additional CSS */
}
```

You should consider using Bootstrap to make life easier for your popup form. It is one of many front-end frameworks that really help to speed up the development process.

You can import bootstrap into your page by following the getting start instructions located here, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Bootstrap uses a grid system for the page which makes it easy to visualize and layout your page. It also allows for multiple breakpoints, so your page will display nicely on all screen sizes.

You can create a pop-up modal and include a "X" to exit by following these instructions, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Once you create a modal, you can start to include your form elements into it by reading this, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/